# Gradient to be across entire background while maintaining image original size

Tags: css, reactjs

I currently have a very small image and plan to use it as a background and
align it to the top right by maintaining its original size.

Meanwhile I want the entire background to have a gradient color.

How can I achieve this?

Cos currently the background images ends up skewing and stretching to the entire background.

To control this, I added back the original image size to it. This works and image is aligned

to top and back to original size.

But the gradient color also ends up becoming small instead of stretching across the background.

Please advice. Thanks.

This is what I have currently.

```
import React from "react";

const MyComponent = (): React.ReactElement => {

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                backgroundImage: [
                    `url('a.png')`,
                    `linear-gradient('130deg', "#53565A 0%", "#000000 100%")`
                ],
                backgroundPosition: `top right`,
                backgroundSize: '305px 75px',
                backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
            }}
        >
            {<div>{'some text'}</div>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

I end up with outcome in following image. The image location is correct, top right. (The image is a white subtle wavy lines)
But I want that gradient (dark black to grey gradient) to extend the full background size and cover all the white space. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulate the div where you have inserted background image with a parent div and add gradient color to it.
Something like this.

```
<parent-div> //Here add gradient color

<background-image-div>

<-- your content -->

</background-image-div>

</parent-div>
```